# clickable bootstrap-datepicker icon with angular directive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, directive, datepicker

I'm using angularjs and I want my bootstrap-datepicker to be shown after clicking in calendar icon. 

Now it's like this:

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker">
    <input type="text" b-datepicker ng-model="date"/> 
    <span class="add-on" ><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Where `b-datepicker` is custom directive. Click in text field shows datepicker, but icon click doesn't work.

Here's sources: http://jsfiddle.net/cPVDn/

My goal is to be like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6QnMB/

I appreciate any help

**UPDATE:**

Here's **solution**: 
 
http://jsfiddle.net/cPVDn/53/

Comment: please post your edit as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting solution as separate answer.

To make icon click work instead of:

```
directive('bDatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attr) {
       el.datepicker();
     }
  };
})
```

one could use something like:

```
directive('bDatepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, el, attr) {
        el.datepicker({});
        var component = el.siblings('[data-toggle="datepicker"]');
        if (component.length) {
            component.on('click', function () {
                el.trigger('focus');
            });
        }
    }
  };
})
```

Here is full snippet with solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/cPVDn/53/

Answer (score 1):

See good plugin from AngularStrap that will solve your problem: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/QAxwgLSWQaYbGzkzeu4g?p=preview).

*JS*

```
.config(function($datepickerProvider) {
  angular.extend($datepickerProvider.defaults, {
    dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    startWeek: 1
  });
})
```

*HTML*

```
<input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="selectedDateAsNumber" 
    data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
    data-date-type="number" 
    data-min-date="02/10/86"
    data-max-date="today"
    data-autoclose="1" 
    name="date2"
    bs-datepicker>
```

See Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rBoa9VwCh8Zd7OWZn4p4?p=preview)</kbd>

---

And this is their [main page](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker)

Comment: I've used angular-bootstrap in my project and I don't want to mix these two, but after Your suggestion I've looked into sources and came up with solution. Thank You!

Comment: This answer is not the best. The answer in question's UPDATE is the real best answer. It simply uses a directive. I think it would be good to have that solution here in this page.

Comment: @hiphip right, he posted the edit 10 month later. But still he uses `bootstrap-datepicker` plugin

Comment: @MaximShoustin, bootstrap-datepicker was mentioned in the question. Than the solution in UPDATE only needs to add a custom "b-datepicker" directive. For sure this is a different solution (so it would be good to place it as an answer), and for me it is the best. Yours is an alternative solution using the AngularStrap lib, that is ok.

Comment: @hiphip agree, SO solution is simplest, hope he will post it as separate answer

Answer (score 0):

In the example in [bootstrap documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) they do it somewhat like this:

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker">
  <input type="text" is-open="opened" datepicker-popup ng-model="date"/> 
  <span class="add-on" ng-click="openAction($e)" ><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

And then in the controller:

```
  $scope.openAction = function ($event) {

    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;   
}
```